# Aws instance returning two IP address on lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I am running my AWS EC2 instance.
Recently i made a IP Address Lookup and found out that it is returning two IP Address.

I went to my EC2 console and checked the "Manage IP Address"  i found it has only one IP address. I am pretty confused how is it happening.

My aws instance is ,
ec2-52-66-19-68.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

---

After looking for the answer I searched all through the Internet still i couldnt find why ?

hence i took the Business support Plan on AWS and the said i am using Load Balancer and through load balancer there will be two IPs.

There exact word if i am not able to explain properly

> spontieapp-880428207.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com is an Elastic load
>   balancer (ELB) and this ELB is associated with 2 availability zones
>   ap-south-1a and ap-south-1b. ELB is designed for high availability and
>   therefore, it will be deployed in 2 AZ's which results in 2 IP
>   addresses for the ELB.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how did you do IP address lookup?

Comment: @DusanBajic  By usinhg this website http://whatismyipaddress.com/hostname-ip,

Comment: and then i searched both the IP address on the browser toolbar and my website only opened

Comment: That tool returns only one address: `Lookup IPv4 Address: 52.66.19.68`

Comment: What browser toolbar?

Comment: I dont know in the 4-5 hours back it was returning two IP's  Any how i confirmed with AWS that is is ELB , ELB is designed for high availability and is deployed at two AZ'a so those two IP's . sorry i was bothered about my DNS configuration